# Epitools oddsratio error in chisq.test

Tags: chi-squared-test, odds-ratio, epidemiology

I am trying to calculate the odds ratio using the epitools package. The counts in 2 cells of my 2x2 table are $< 10$ so I keep receiving the following error "Error in chisq.test(xx, correct = correction) : (converted from warning) Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect". I tried defining the method as "fisher" and "small" but I keep getting the same error. How can I get this test to run?

```r
install.packages('epitools')
library(epitools)
mat1 <- c(15, 49)
mat2 <- c(2, 7)
mat <- rbind(mat1,mat2)
mat
oddsratio(mat)
oddsratio.fisher(mat)
oddsratio.small(mat)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, Katie!

Comment: To the close-voters, this seems on-topic to me!

Comment: When I run your code, I do not get an error, I get a warning, and the output spits out just fine as shown in the answer from James. How does an "error convert from a warning" in R?

Comment: @AdamO, the best lead I saw was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754921/1834244 which suggests there might have been a change to the value of `warn` within `options()`

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually getting an error, you are getting a warning. At least when I run your code,

From a programmatic perspective, the warning comes from the subroutine `chisq.test`. Each of the methods (Fisher and small) use separate methods to calculate the *standard errors* for the OR, but it's still the same uncorrected OR as the point estimate - thus the same warning.

"Correction" refers to using an Agresti-Couli type correction which adds 1 (or 0.5) to either the diagonal or all table cell entries. This replaces the empirical odds ratio with a biased but much less variable alternative that behaves better in small samples.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `oddsratio`, `oddsratio.fisher` and `oddsratio.small` all calculate a "regular" chi-squared statistic for reporting each time: you can see this in the example output for `oddsratio.fisher(mat)` below (the `$p.value` table, `chi.square` column).

So each of these variants of oddsratio is triggering the approximation warning on each run from the call to `chisq.test()`.

The test is still running (for me at least): if you try `chisq.test(mat)` which uses the base stats package function, you will see that this message is printed as a Warning, rather than an Error.

```r
oddsratio.fisher(mat)
$data
  col1 col2 Total
mat1    15   49    64
mat2     2    7     9
Total   17   56    73

$measure                        
                         NA
odds ratio with 95% C.I. estimate     lower    upper
                    mat1  1.00000        NA       NA
                    mat2  1.07043 0.1766049 11.63845

$p.value
                         NA
two-sided midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
     mat1         NA           NA         NA
     mat2  0.9784459            1  0.9356279

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "Conditional MLE & exact CI from 'fisher.test'"
Warning message:
In chisq.test(xx, correct = correction) :
Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Mine is still printing as an error instead of a warning. Maybe it is a versional difference, but I am using the latest update.

Comment: OK (I'm on R 4.2.2, and epitools 0.5-10.1). If you still get the output at all, then you can treat this message as a warning about the appropriateness of the chi-squared test for your data; if it's an error that prevents the output from printing then that's more complex!

Comment: This should be a Warning. Your initial question notes this is an "Error...converted from warning", which may relate to your settings. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754423/how-to-solve-error-converted-from-warning